# Как сделать свой переключатель PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, switch, qcheckbox

Я хочу сделать кнопку-переключатель, которая еще в разные стороны ездит, когда на нее тыкаешь.

Я поискал по интернету, нашел одну статью вчера. Но успешно потерял ее и лишился единственного найденного примера) Я знаю, что нужно каким-то образом перерисовать `QAbstractButton` или `QPushButton`, но каким конкретно образом - не знаю.

Собственно, я бы обнял того человека, который дал бы минимальный пример, чтобы понять, как вообще перерисовываются виджеты. А также объяснить, как менять положение этой кнопки на фоне (ну когда на нее тыкаешь, там ее часть вправо-влево ездит).

Что-то типа этого:

[image: Этого]

Comment: Посмотрите тут [Switch button in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806987/switch-button-in-pyqt)

Comment: Спасибо, это именно та статья)

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое решение - использовать таблицу стилей с `QCheckBox`.
Просто отредактируйте таблицу стилей для флажка.

Другое решение можно увидеть здесь [Toggle switch на PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843345/toggle-switch-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5/843414#843414)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

switch = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
switch.setStyleSheet('''
    QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked {
        image: url(switch_off.png);
    }
    QCheckBox::indicator:checked {
        image: url(switch_on.png);
    }
''')

switch.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**switch_off.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**switch_on.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно просто. Это не совсем то, но о подобном ходе я даже и не думал, возьму на заметку)

Comment: @CSharpLooser а другое решение?

Comment: Я просто перерисовал QAbstractButton. В принципе получилось неплохо, но без анимации. Как ее добавить - точно пока не знаю, хотя пара идей есть. Завтра их опробую.

Comment: @CSharpLooser вам в помощь https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825815 :) если что, показывайте пример, что-то придумаем

Comment: Спасибо за тему, завтра почитаю. Жалко, правда, что на плюсах. Я их знаю не так хорошо, но, думаю, разберусь)

Comment: @CSharpLooser смотрите внимательно там есть и PyQt

Comment: @CSharpLooser вы решили данный вопрос?